Is there any possible way to connect monaco editor react with eclipse.jdt.ls language server for multiple users
I’m implementing a web-based code editor with IntelliSense support for Java using the Eclipse JDT Language Server (JDT LS) via LSP. I run the JDT LS in a Node.js application as a child process, and handle IntelliSense through a WebSocket connection to the editor. However, as the number of users increases, the CPU usage of my Node.js instances spikes to 95-100%. Is there a way to scale up and manage this efficiently?
I attempted to run a single instance of the Eclipse JDT Language Server (JDT LS) and connect it to all users, but it only works for the first user who connects. Subsequent users experience issues where the requests from the editor are sent correctly, but there is no response from the LSP.
